# Excel: Find the most common value in array given a certain value (IF, Index, Mode)

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, indexing, mode

I'm trying to find the most common value in a range given a previuous value occurs, so for instance, if Shared mailbox (Col C) is equal to *Finance* tell me the most common *team number* (Col B) of the users who access it:

The function I have so far is (obviously ignore the absolute cell references)

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$20,MODE(MATCH($C$2:$C$20,$C$2:$C$20,0)))
```

I could do this with a pivot but I need to insert the value into a cell and vlookup in a pivot wont cut it. Also there are tens of thousands of rows. But essentially the pivot result is what I'm looking to get to, just in a cell via a formula.

Here is an example of the table, a pivot and a peek at the formula and results.

[Excel image with pivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wasMR.png)

Any and all help is welcome.
Cheers
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for this formula:

```
=MODE.SNGL(IF(C1:C999="Finance",B1:B999))
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

p.s. you can replace the hard-coded `"Finance"` with any cell reference.

---

**EDIT**

Indeed if there's only one matched row, or two rows with different values, the `MODE` will fail because there is actually no single mode. You want then to return the "first" match, therefore wrap the formula inside `IFERROR` with an `INDEX/MATCH` alternative:

```
=IFERROR(MODE.SNGL(IF(C1:C999="Finance",B1:B999)),INDEX(B:B,MATCH("Finance",C:C,0)))
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thanks A.S.H, just like @ProgSnob below great and clean response, the only issue being times when there is only one or two values (similar or differing) it returns #N/A, any ideas on returning the first response, or indeed either?

Comment: @Mchapple then wrap it inside `IFERROR` to use an `INDEX/MATCH` alternative. See the EDIT.

Comment: **Perfect** and just what I needed. Thanks to you and @ProgSnob both really good responses.

Comment: @Mchapple you're welcome. I up-voted ProgSnob's answer on your behalf to give the due credit to his answer. :)

Comment: cheers, yeah I'm too new and squeeky to be allowed to vote it seems ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array formulas. Use the `mode` function over an `if`

```
{=MODE(IF($C$3:$C$18=F4,$B$3:$B$18))}
```

Refer to image for example:
[image]

Comment: Great response and pretty clean too, Thank you. Just one small issue, if there is a count less than 3 against something then it returns #N/A. So for anything where it has 1 or 2 entries, and even if they are differing or exact the respoinse is #N/A. Any ideas on getting back the first entry as a default?

Comment: I think #N/A is telling you that there is no 'most' frequent team. All teams have had equal contribution.